# object keeps resetting size into array after onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactstrap

I'm trying to submit a form however, when i double submit again while changing the size value, it overrides the first object's selection. I'm using react-redux. I've tried using logic to select the correct value before passing the 2nd array. these are my codes.

```
    var roastedHazelnutLatte = {
    name:'Roasted Hazelnut Latte',
    size: 0,
    price:5,
    regularQty:0,
    oatlyQty:0,
    customisation: ''
} 

//drink size
const roastedHazelnutSize = e => {
    var{name,value} = e.target;
    var value = parseInt(value,10)
    roastedHazelnutLatte.size = value
}
//drink quantity
const roastedHazelnutRegularQty = e => {
    var {name,value} =e.target;
    var value = parseInt(value,10)
    roastedHazelnutLatte.regularQty = value
}
const roastedHazelnutOatlyQty = e => {
    var{name,value} = e.target
    var value = parseInt(value,10)
    roastedHazelnutLatte.oatlyQty = value
}
//drink customisation
const roastedHazelnutCustomisation = e => {
    const {name,value}=e.target;
    roastedHazelnutLatte.customisation = value
}
//on click add name of drink: hazelnut latte
const addHazelnutLatte = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    addItem.orders.push(roastedHazelnutLatte)
    console.log(addItem)
}`
```

Dropdown codes:

```
<Input type='select' name='size' onChange={e=>roastedHazelnutSize(e)}>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value={300}>300ml</option>
    <option value={1000}>1L</option>
</Input>
```

onClick codes:

```
<Button onClick={e=>addHazelnutLatte(e)}> Add</Button>
```

i'm thinking about setting state. but i'm not very sure how to go about it as well.

Comment: This is very weird. Are you trying to keep the state within pure JS object variables? Providing the code of the whole component wouldd be more useful.

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to keep the state within pure JS. So whenever I add a new array of object, the size of the drink overrides the previously added arrays as well. @WiktorBednarz

Comment: I think that it would be a much better solution to keep this state within `useEffect` hook provided to you by React. This approach is very fragile and goes against some very basic good code standards.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

However it would be even better if you would make this a standard, uncotrolled form - since you don't have to process the data before dispatching it. You've got few solutions available here:
https://medium.com/@ReactEurope/which-react-form-library-should-you-use-in-your-app-in-2020-469894c687d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the first object gets changed in the array is that the `roastedHazelnutLatte`  object reference is always maintained even after you push it in array `orders`.
You should update function to this

```
const addHazelnutLatte = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    addItem.orders.push({...roastedHazelnutLatte})
    console.log(addItem)
}
```

As an example

```
const obj ={a: 1, b: 2}
const arr = []
arr.push(obj)
obj.a = 5;
arr.push(obj)
console.log(arr) // would result [a: 5, b: 2}, a: 5, b: 2}]
```

To fix this you can create a new object using ES6 spread operator, or, `Object.assign` but that's again would do a shallow copy on the object and not a deep copy.

```
const obj ={a: 1, b: 2}
const arr = []
arr.push({...obj})
obj.a = 5;
arr.push({...obj})
console.log(arr) // would result [a: 1, b: 2}, a: 5, b: 2}]
```

Comment: oh. it works! but right now, if i had submit the same size say, 300, but i made changes to the qty of drinks and i want it to override the initial array how should i go about it? @brijesh-pant

Comment: well, certainly it's not the best way to track the orders as you're doing above. 
`orders` can be made a hashmap object, that tracks each order on the basis of order id as a key. This way you can track and update each order individually on the basis of order id, order item being the `roastedHazelnutLatte` value.